# Juju bootstrap Error "no matching tools available"

Tags: juju, maas

System specification: Ubuntu 15.10, maas 1.25

juju bootstrap returns following error:

```
INFO juju.environs.bootstrap tools.go:77 looking for bootstrap tools: version=<nil>
ERROR juju.cmd supercommand.go:429 failed to bootstrap environment: no matching tools available
```

Here is " dpkg -l | grep juju" :

```
ii  juju                                                 1.25.5-    ubuntu1~15.10.2~juju1              all          next generation service orchestration system
ii  juju-core                                            1.25.5-0ubuntu1~15.10.2~juju1              amd64        Juju is devops distilled - client
ii  juju-quickstart                                      2.2.4+bzr147+ppa42~ubuntu15.10.1           all          Easy configuration of Juju environments
ii  python-jujubundlelib                                 0.4.1-1~ubuntu15.10.1~ppa1                 all          A Python2 library for working with Juju bundles.
ii  python-jujuclient                                    0.50.3-1~ubuntu15.10.1~ppa1                amd64        Python API client for juju-c
```

Here is the result of "**juju bootstrap --upload-tools --debug**"

```
2016-05-25 20:53:33 INFO juju.cmd supercommand.go:37 running juju [1.25.5-wily-amd64 gc]
2016-05-25 20:53:33 WARNING juju.environs config.go:168 Config attribute "tools-metadata-url" (https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools/streams/v1/index2.sjson) is deprecated.
It is replaced by "agent-metadata-url" attribute.
Your configuration should be updated to set "agent-metadata-url" as follows
agent-metadata-url:   https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools/streams/v1/index2.sjson.
2016-05-25 20:53:33 WARNING juju.environs config.go:168 Config attribute "tools-metadata-url"    (https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools/streams/v1/index2.sjson) is deprecated.
It is replaced by "agent-metadata-url" attribute.
Your configuration should be updated to set "agent-metadata-url" as follows
agent-metadata-url: https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools/streams/v1/index2.sjson.
2016-05-25 20:53:33 DEBUG juju.provider.maas environprovider.go:28 opening environment "maas".
2016-05-25 20:53:33 WARNING juju.environs.config config.go:1430 unknown config field "metadata-source"
2016-05-25 20:53:33 WARNING juju.environs.config config.go:1430 unknown config field "metadata-source"
2016-05-25 20:53:34 DEBUG juju.environs.configstore disk.go:351 writing jenv file
2016-05-25 20:53:34 DEBUG juju.environs.configstore disk.go:475 writing jenv file to /home/rastin/.juju/environments/maas.jenv
2016-05-25 20:53:34 INFO juju.network network.go:242 setting prefer-ipv6 to false
2016-05-25 20:53:34 INFO juju.cmd cmd.go:129 Bootstrapping environment "maas"
2016-05-25 20:53:34 DEBUG juju.environs.bootstrap bootstrap.go:103 environment "maas" supports service/machine networks: true
2016-05-25 20:53:34 DEBUG juju.environs.bootstrap bootstrap.go:105 network management by juju enabled: true
2016-05-25 20:53:34 WARNING juju.environs.config config.go:1430 unknown config field "metadata-source"
2016-05-25 20:53:34 WARNING juju.environs.config config.go:1430 unknown config field "metadata-source"
2016-05-25 20:53:34 INFO juju.cmd cmd.go:129 Starting new instance for initial state server
2016-05-25 20:53:34 INFO juju.provider.maas environ.go:137 address allocation feature disabled; using "juju-br0" bridge for all containers
2016-05-25 20:53:34 DEBUG juju.cmd.juju common.go:102 Destroying environment.
2016-05-25 20:53:34 INFO juju.cmd cmd.go:129 Bootstrap failed, destroying environment
2016-05-25 20:53:34 INFO juju.provider.common destroy.go:22 destroying environment "maas"
2016-05-25 20:53:34 INFO juju.provider.common destroy.go:33 destroying instances
2016-05-25 20:53:34 INFO juju.provider.common destroy.go:53 destroying storage
2016-05-25 20:53:34 ERROR juju.cmd supercommand.go:429 failed to bootstrap environment: no matching tools available
```

May be it is because of UBUNTU 15.10?!

**I fixed the error:**

> just purged all juju packages and installed juju-core (1.25.5) , it passed that error!

**Now I have another Error:**

```
DEBUG juju.provider.maas volumes.go:217 acquire maas node: missing volume label for id "4"
ERROR juju.cmd supercommand.go:429 failed to bootstrap environment: bootstrap instance started but did not change to Deployed state: instance "/MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-044f771c-2200-11e6-936a-001372564120/" is started but not deployed
```

it seems the latest error is because of **bootstrap-timeout** which defined in **~/.juju/environmet.yaml**, which cause the bootstrap timeout.

I set the timeout to a big number and here is the result, after installing and downloading all packages on node:

```
ERROR juju.cmd supercommand.go:429 failed to bootstrap environment: subprocess encountered error code 1
```

I deleted the node and recommissioned it again, my MAAS vesion was 1.9.3.

**Do I need bootstrap the node with root?**
The answer is no!.

**Finally**  I found what cause the latest error, it was some spaces after "," in no-proxy definition in environment.yaml file.

Comment: Can you share the outpput $ dpkg -l | grep juju

Comment: I Added the result of " dpkg -l | grep juju" on Quetsion

Answer (score 1):

```
juju bootstrap --upload-tools
```

This will upload a set of the right tools into your bootstrap node.

Comment: I added result of juju bootstrap --upload-tools on Question, Same error as before.

Answer (score 1):

1) just purged all juju packages and installed juju-core (1.25.5)

2) I set the timeout to a big number in juju environment.yaml

3) I deleted the node and recommissioned it again (MAAS vesion was 1.9.3)

4) I added no-proxy: 'list ip and your local network' in juju environment.yaml

5) I replaced spaces after "," in no-proxy definition in juju environment.yaml file

Bootstrap completed without error!

Comment: The you should put the steps here, not into your question, this way this would be a proper answer, as it is now it is only a commentary.

Answer (score 0):

You may be running into [bug #1517632](https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1517632) where having an outdated distro-info can result in a "no matching tools" error (see [comment #15](https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1517632/comments/15) for more info).  Try updating the distro-info-data package and see if you can bootstrap.

Comment: Done,  again same error!

Comment: I just purged all juju packages and installed juju-core (1.25.5) , it passed that error!

Comment: Now I have another error: ERROR juju.cmd supercommand.go:429 failed to bootstrap environment: bootstrap instance started but did not change to Deployed state: instance "/MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-044f771c-2200-11e6-936a-001372564120/" is started but not deployed

Comment: I have hit this problem using my vMAAS before.  Recommissioning the nodes and trying again has helped.  Also, upgrading my MAAS from 1.9.1 to 1.9.3 seemed to work around the issue.

Comment: I deleted the node and recommissioned it again, my MAAS vesion was 1.9.3.Do I need bootstrap the node with root ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to.  The error "is started but not deployed" means that in MAAS, the node didn't move to a "Deployed" state, and therefore juju thinks the provisioning failed or stalled.  If you're using physical nodes and they take longer than 10 minutes to provision, you may need to increase the timeout for bootstrap with "bootstrap-timeout: 1800" in your environments.yaml.

Comment: I increased the timeout earlier and I got another error, as you see I updated my question too, here is latest error: ERROR juju.cmd supercommand.go:429 failed to bootstrap environment: subprocess encountered error code 1